# On the homotopy groups of the spectrum $D(n)$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am interested in learning about the homotopy groups of the spectrum $D(n)$ at the prime $2$ which is defined as the cofibre of the diagonal map

$$Sp^{2^{n-1}}S^0 \to Sp^{2^n}S^0$$

where $Sp$ is the symmetric power functor. In particular, I am interested in the spectrum $D(2)$. Indeed, I imagine that there would not be a complete description of these groups as the $D(0)=S^0$ and $D(1)=\Sigma P_{-1}$ tells me that even the cases of $n=0,1$ is quit difficult. But, I am still wondering if there exists any computations, at least in a range, on homotopy groups of these spectra. In particular, does the equality

$$\mathrm{hocolim}\ D(n)=H\mathbb{Z}/2\ (*)$$

suffice to show that for any $n$ then exist $b_n$ so that $\pi_iD(n)=0$ for $i>b_n$?! I would be very grateful if someone can point out at a reference with some state of art computations on (homotopy groups of) these spectra. Thank you very much in advanced.

**ADDED** By work of Mitchell and Priddy we know tht $H^*D(n)$ has a basis consisting of classes $Sq^Iu_n$ with $I$ being an admissible sequence of length not more than $n$ and $u_n\in H^0D(n)$ is a generaor. In particular, I think, this tells me that $\pi_0D(n)=0$ if $n>0$ and the integer $c_n$ in the comments below will not exist unless we assume $c_n>0$. What I read off from $(*)$ is that for any $i>0$ there exists a $d_i>0$ so that $\pi_iD(n)=0$ for $n>d_i$.

**Further Addendum** Thanks to the comments below, I noticed that the kernel of the map $A=H^*H\mathbb{Z}/2\to H^*D(n)$ induced by $i_n:D(n)\to H\mathbb{Z}$ has a basis of all classes $Sq^I$ with $I$ admissible and of length at least $n+1$. Here, $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1})$ is admissible if $i_j\geqslant 2i_{j+1}$. I think the admissible sequence $I$ of length $n+1$ and least dimension would be $I=(2^n,2^{n-1},\ldots,2,1)$ whose dimension is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i=2^{n+1}-1$. Therefore, I conclude that $i^*$ is an isomorphism in $H^*$ for $*\leqslant 2^{n+1}-2$. Hence, if $n>0$ then
$$i_*:\pi_*D(n)\to \pi_*H\mathbb{Z}/2$$
is an isomorphism for $*\leqslant 2^{n+1}-2$. Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: Not to mention the case $n=0$,

Comment: The equality suffices to show that for any $n$ there exists $c_n$, increasing, so that $\pi _i(D(n)=0$ for $i<c_n$.  And the answer to your last question is likely to be negative for all $n$.  It is certainly false for $n=0$.

Comment: @user43326 Thanks for the comments. I have added some additional notes at the end of my question. Would it make more sense now?

Comment: We get $H^*)D(n))\cong H^*(HZ/2)$ for $*\leq 2^n$ or something like that from Mitchell Priddy, so by Whitehead, we get the same for $\pi _*$.

Comment: Another point.  What you say at the end of the first added paragraph is that the $i$-th homotopy group of $D(n)$ vanishes for $n>>i$, equivalently, $i<<n$.

Comment: @user43326 Yes. According to the hocolim the homotopy grops above dimension $0$ must stablise to the trivial group. So, would this be a natural thing to happen?!

Comment: Actually I think I was long.  For the colimit to be zero, it doesn't have to stabilize to 0.  For ex, you can have a sequence with $0$ appearing once in a while.  But in your case, there are many arguments to guarantee the stabilization property.  You also have a cofibration $D(n-1)\to D(n) \to \Sigma ^{a(n)}M(n)$ which helps.

Comment: @user43326 But, you agree with $i_*$ being an isomorphism in the above range as far as $n>0$ ?! The problem with the cofibration, actually $a(n)=n$, is that I don't know about homotopy groups of $M(n)$, although the cohomology is known to have basis consisting of all $Sq^I$ with $l(I)=n$. I wonder if this can give us more information?! Should it admit a $CW$-spectrum model whose bottom cell is in dimension $2^n-1$ and whose top cell is in dimension $2^{n+1}-2$ ?!